# Non-linear "animation" of numeric value with JavaScript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I want to make an animation like this one in Google Analytics on active users.

[image: Analytics counter]

---

I saw some scripts that do the animation, but they do it in linear mode, like, the speed is the same from 0 to XXX, I want it to start slowly, gain speed, and finish slowly again.

How would I do this in javascript/jquery?

---

As requested, what I tried:

```
<span id="counter">0</span>    

$(function ()
{
    var $counter = $('#counter'),
        startVal = $counter.text(),
        currentVal,
        endVal = 250;


    currentVal = startVal;
    var i = setInterval(function ()
    {
        if (currentVal === endVal)
        {
            clearInterval(i);
        }
        else
        {
            currentVal++;
            $counter.text(currentVal);
        }
    }, 100);


});
```

But I don't think it's the way to go...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would use jQuery's built-in animation for this.

If you pass a function to the `step` option for `.animate()`, it will be fired for each tick during animation.  That way, jQuery will handle all of the easing and what not for you.  You just need to handle the data.

```
$({countValue:0}).animate(
    {countValue:346},
    {
        duration: 5000, /* time for animation in milliseconds */
        step: function (value) { /* fired every "frame" */
            console.log(value);
        }
    }
);
```

In the console, you will see values between 0 and 346, complete with easing.

Comment: +1 Very neat solution, wasn't aware of that jQuery functionality.